# Include Comments in Cpp/H files in Pybind11 bindings

Tags: c++, pybind11

Essentially I have comments in a the header file for functions in classes being bound with Pybind11 and is there a way to move the C++ docs to pybind11 easily? I couldn't find references to this in the pybind documentation, and although I can manually copy and paste the docs, doing so is a pain.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a tool called [robotpy-build](https://github.com/robotpy/robotpy-build) which parses headers and generates pybind11 code from it, including docstrings.

It uses a python package (that I also wrote) called [cxxheaderparser](https://github.com/robotpy/cxxheaderparser) that parses header files and can extract doxygen comments for each function/attribute. The doxygen comments are transformed into docstrings using [sphinxify](https://pypi.org/project/sphinxify/) (written by a collaborator of mine).

The author of pybind11 wrote a clang-based tool [pybind11_mkdoc](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11_mkdoc) that extracts the headers and comments to generate docstrings, but I haven't tried it.